# How to get generated access token from web resource with keycloak auth

Tags: c#, api, jwt, keycloak, webclient

I am developing an application on WPF in order to quickly work with a web application via api (**clarification: login and password are required for authorization**). The essence of the api work is to substitute the generated token to the method, which is updated every 4 hours.

I can manually log into the site every 4 hours and collect this token from devtools, but I would like to automate this process and write a small console application that would automatically collect this token.
I tried to find a suitable solution for me, but unfortunately I did not succeed. Is there a way to do this?

P.S. The authorization page has its own yurl. After successful authorization, redirection to the service occurs.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to track all the requests to the api and find the one that generates the token.

Comment: @RaduHatos token generates when the authorization is completed, i cannot use api methods without token

Comment: Yes, but you also can automate the authorization process which will lead to token.

Comment: @RaduHatos Ok, but is there another way to solve this? There is no way to download fiddler on my work computer

Comment: Use Network tab from your browser devtools. This is for Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ . What you need to do is to repeat all the steps for getting the token and try to follow the same requests in your console app.

Comment: @RaduHatos I've been trying to reilize it, but the catch is that the service uses authorization through the keycloak.

Comment: I'm not familiar with keycloak but there should be something. On a quick search I found this: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak#test_your_new_client . Check it out maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser DevTools and capture the request which leads to the Token. Then write a code in your console application to call that request with HTTPClient or whatever library you want and you have the token to work with.